# Finding numerical value of hyperbolic sine functions

Tags: trigonometry

I have no idea what to do at all, the book gives no relevant examples so I had to give up.

I am suppose to find $\sinh(\ln 2)$ I don't even know where to start. I think I need to use the form $\dfrac{e^{\ln2}-e^{-\ln2}}2$ but I get confused on how to do that as well.

Comment: Just use the fact that $e^{\ln x}=x$ for all $x>0$ and $e^{-x}=\frac 1{e^x}$ for all $x\in\mathbb R$.

Comment: Recall that logarithm is the inverse of exponentiation, i.e. for $\mathrm{e}^x = 2$, the real solution is $x= \ln 2$, now substitute the solution back into the equation (_lightbulb_)

Comment: I know I should never ask why, but is there an easy way to remember that?

Comment: "The logarithm is the inverse of the exponential" is often the *definition* of the logarithm.

Comment: So e raised to the ln2 just means e to the $loge^2$

Comment: @Jordan: No. $\ln 2 = r$ means that $e^r=2$. So $e^{\ln 2} = e^r =$`?`.

Comment: I don't know what that means.

Comment: @Jordan: $\ln$ is a function that, given an input, will return to you the exponent to which you need to raise $e$ in order to get the input. That is, if we write $\ln (3) = r$, that means that $r$ is the number such that $e^r$ is equal to $3$. If we write $\ln(5)=s$, that means that $s$ is the number such that $e^s = 5$. $\ln(e^2) = 2$, because $2$ is precisely the exponent we need to raise $e$ to in order to get $e^2$ as the answer. So when we write "$\ln 2 = r$" that means that if we do $e^r$< we will get $2$ as the result. So, if $\ln 2 = r$, then $e^{\ln 2} = e^r$. What do you get?

Comment: I don't know. ln2 I guess but I don't know why.

Comment: Jordan, see the first comment and ask yourself what '$x$' is. An 'inverse function' is something that *undoes* some original function. So if $y=e^x$, the natural logarithm 'undoes' the exponential function, i.e. $\ln y = x$.

Comment: ln is just loge?

Comment: I got the answer with my calculator I guess that is good enough.

Comment: $\ln(x)$ is $\log_e(x)$ and it's the inverse of $e^x$. You also need to know that $f(f^{-1}(x))=f^{-1}(f(x))=x.$

Comment: So logex = x? And the function of the derivative

Comment: That should be the function of the derivative is equal to the derivative of the function which is equal to x?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I've mentioned before, trying to pass calculus through sheer memorization effort is doom to fail.

Here you are asking of a way to memorize the fact that the 
$$e^{\ln 2} = 2.$$
This is simply a consequence of what the logarithm function is supposed to **be**.

Logarithms are the *inverses* of exponentials. Inverse functions are functions that "undo" what the "original" function does. The logarithm base $a$ "undoes" exponentiation base $a$; exponentiation base $a$ "undoes" the logarithm base $a$. We **define** $\log_a(b)$ to be the number $r$ exactly when $a^r = b$. The statement "$\log_a(b)=r$" and the statement "$a^r = b$" mean the same thing, just like the statement "$\frac{6}{2}=3$" and the statement "$3\times 2= 6$" mean the same thing (because "$\frac{6}{2}$" means "the number that multiplied by $2$ gives $6$").

That is, we **always** have
$$ a^{\log_a(x)} = x\quad\text{and}\quad \log_a(a^x) = x\quad\text{for all values of }x$$

These identities are simply a consequence of the fact that each function "undoes" the other function. It is a waste of mental effort to try to memorize them: there's just too many of them! One for every possible value of $a$. It's far better (and more productive in the long run) to *understand why* they are true, so that they can be internalized as *conclusions* rather than memorized "magic spells" that have no meaning.

In particular, since $\ln x$ is the logarithm base $e$ of $x$, $\ln x = \log_e(x)$, the fact that the exponential undoes the logarithm and the logarithm undoes the exponential means that
$$e^{\ln(x)} = x\quad\text{and}\quad \ln(e^x) = x\quad\text{for all values of }x.$$

So $e^{\ln 5} = 5$, $\ln(e^3) = 3$, $e^{\ln\pi} = \pi$, $17^{\log_{17}(42.4)} = 42.4$, and so on and so forth.

Since we also have that, among the properties of logarithms, $r\ln(b) = \ln(b^r)$,

So:
$$\sinh(\ln(2)) = \frac{e^{\ln 2} - e^{-\ln 2}}{2} = \frac{e^{\ln 2} - e^{\ln(2^{-1})}}{2} = \frac{2 - 2^{-1}}{2} = \frac{\quad 2 - \frac{1}{2}\quad}{2} = \frac{2}{2} - \frac{\;\frac{1}{2}\;}{2} = 1 - \frac{1}{4} = \frac{3}{4}.$$

Comment: I still don't get $a^{\log_a(x)} = x\quad\text{and}\quad \log_a(a^x) = x\quad\text{for all values of }x$ I know I am stupid but I just can't get it for some reason. If I have 2 raised to a number that is suppose to make a number x than how do I know that equals x? That doesn't make sense to me, to me it could be anything.

Comment: The reason is that $\log_a(x)$ is **defined** to be **the** number to which you need to raise $a$ in order to get $x$ as the answer. You are raising $a$ to the number which is supposed to give you $x$ as the answer; how do you know that $x$ is the answer? Because that's what the number you are raising $a$ to is *supposed* to do.

Comment: So I need a to equal x by using an exponent. so $a^x$=x? I don't get that. If I replace a with 3 and x with 9 I get x don't I? So shouldn't it be equal to a?

Comment: $\log_a(x)$ is the only thing you can put in the empty box in $$a^{\Box} = x$$to make that equation true. There is one, and only one number that can fill that box and make the equation true. That number is what $\log_a(x)$ is defined to be equal to.

Comment: So I need to make a equal to x by raising it by an exponent, I don't understand how raising it by x makes a x. Like if I am trying to make 4 = 16 I raise it by 2 not 16.

Comment: @Jordan: Nobody said "raise it by $x$". We said: the number you need to raise $a$ to in order to get $x$ is $\log_a(x)$. That's not "x", it's **the logarithm base $a$ of $x$**. The fact that $2^{4}=16$ tells you that $\log_2(16) = 4$.

Comment: I think I get it now, hopefully I can still remember on monday. Thank you.